# jQuery fadeIn() or SlideDown()

Tags: jquery, fadein

My jQuery code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#comment_submit").on('click', function () {
        var message = $("#pc_message").val();

        var uid = $("#uid").val();
        var from_uid = $("#from_uid").val();

        if (message == '') {
            alert("Message is missing!!");
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "pro_profile.php?action=do_comment",
            data: "message=" + message + "&uid=" + uid + "&from_uid=" + from_uid,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#show_profile_comments').html(response);
                document.getElementById('pc_message').value = '';
                document.getElementById('pc_message').focus();
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I want `#show_profile_comments` to be fadeIn or slideDown effect, when I use either of these two jQuery functions it doesn't fadeIn neither slideDown.

I'm trying this;

```
$('#show_profile_comments').fadeIn("slow").html(response);
```

But it doesn't works and the message is posted without having any effect. Is there something wrong in the code?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the suggestion Arun posted will fadeIn the whole table on which that id is used. If you used to show fadeIn effect on each `bit of table or row` (which is apparaent from your code) then assign an id e.g. add `id="lcb"` to the table's `<td>` and Replace;

```
$('#show_profile_comments').html(response);
```

with;

```
$('#show_profile_comments').html(response);
$('#lcb').hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

This will give fadeIn effect to separate td-s

Answer (score 1):

One probable reason could be the element is already visible, then methods like `fadeIn` or `slideDown` will not have any effect...

Try

```
$('#show_profile_comments').hide().html(response).fadeIn("slow");
```